# How to handle the result received from Confluent Kafka consumer?

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

Hi I am working on Confluent Kafka. I have one consumer which returns ConsumeResult. Below is my implementation of consumer.

```
public ConsumeResult<string, GenericRecord> Consume(string topic)
    {
      consumer.Subscribe(topic);
      ConsumeResult<string, GenericRecord> result;
      try
      {
        result = consumer.Consume();
        return result;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        this.logger.Error("KafkaClient", $"Error sending message '{e.Message}'");
        return null;
      }
    }
```

I am calling this method as

```
public ConsumeResult<string, GenericRecord> SubscribeAsync()
    {
      return this.consumerClient.Consume(productEventTopicName);
    }
```

Then finally from controller I am calling as

> var productEvents = this.eventDispatcher.SubscribeAsync();

Now I want to handle this result. I know I can get one field as

```
response.Message.Value.TryGetValue("Version", out object result);
```

I want to get all fields in one go. My confusion is Do I need to go required model based on the data received from the consumer or existing model I can use? If I use existing model then If tomorrow new fields comes in consumer result then how our model will handle it? Can someone help me to understand this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use GenericRecord, the deserializer will contact the schema registry to pull new schema information as the producer sends it.

In order to parse new fields however, you must stop the consumer and explicitly add the code to handle those properties accordingly. That problem is not very specific to Kafka